# sql server 2008 r2 - conditional pseudo-column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. One of events and one of articles.
Each event has a linked article, but articles can exist without corresponding events.
What I want to do is get a list of all articles and have a bool pseudo-column that indicates if the article has a linked event or not.
i.e. If exists a row in [Events] where ArticleID = the current ArticleID then true, if not than false.

Comment: You can do as in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992673/get-current-record-for-a-subquery-in-t-sql/5992772#5992772

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson - Thank you for the comment. That's also a good solution, but the one by BobTodd is better since it's persisted (If I can get it to work eventually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a persisted computed column

First create a function to return true or false

```
-- This function will provide the computed column definition 
CREATE FUNCTION udf_article_has_events ( @id int ) 
RETURNS bit  
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 

BEGIN   

DECLARE @retval bit

set @retval = 0
if exists(select * from [Events] where ArticleId = @id) 
    set @retval = 1


RETURN @retval

END
```

Then add computed column like this

```
Alter TABLE [dbo.Article] Add HasEvents As dbo.udf_events_exist(id)
```

Comment: @BobTodd - Just one issue - I get the following error: "Computed column 'HasEvents' in table 'cmsArticle' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic"

Comment: ive added the schemabinding attribute

Comment: @Elad - I'm pretty sure you will not be able to persist this. The value of the function will change if you delete a row from the `Events` table.

Comment: @Martin - I recreated the udf with schemabinding and now I get another error: "Computed column 'HasEvents' in table 'cmsArticle' cannot be persisted because the column does user or system data access."

Comment: @Martin - I'm starting to realize that myself. Thank you.

Comment: @BobTodd - Sorry, but persisting this one doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @elad does it need to be persisted?

Comment: Works, just without the persist. Thank you!

Comment: @Hogan the OP did specifically ask for a pseudo-column, not alternatives

Comment: @BobTodd -- ah Oracle thingy, just looked it up.

Answer (score 1):

If the value must be persisted, you need an after insert and delete trigger on the Event table to update the Article.HasEvents column

```
CREATE TRIGGER SetHAsEvents
ON dbo.[Events]
FOR INSERT 
AS
   Update Article Set HasEvents = dbo.udf_article_has_events(inserted.ArticleId)
   Where Id = inserted.ArticleId
GO
```

Added advantage of a persisted column is that it can be indexed

Answer (score 1):

Create a view from this

```
 SELECT *, CASE
             WHEN E.ArticleID IS NULL THEN false 
             ELSE true
           END as EventExist
 FROM Article A
 LEFT JOIN Events E ON A.ArticleID = E.ArticleID
```